# C program: keyboard does not recognise enter using getch()

Tags: c, enter, getch

So I'm trying to mask my password with `'*'`.
So far this code works with backspace and all. However, when I hit enter, it doesn't do anything at all and thus, I couldn't move on with the program.

This is what I have so far:

```
    printf("Password:");

    fflush(stdout);
    while((ch=mygetch()) != EOF || ch != 13 || z<sizeof(password)-1){
            if(ch==127 && z>0){
                    printf("\b \b"); fflush(stdout);
                    z--; password[z] = '\0';
            }
            else if(isalnum(ch)){
                    putchar('*');
                    password[z++] = (char)ch;
            }
    }
    password[z] = '\0';
    printf("password: %s", password);
```

And I have mygetch defined on this function:

```
    int mygetch(){
        int ch;
        struct termios oldt, newt;

        tcgetattr (STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
        newt=oldt;
        newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
        tcsetattr (STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
        ch = getchar();
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);

        return ch;
    }
```

I tried putting an `if-statement` inside, that `if(ch==13) break;`, it will break the `while-loop`. However, it still didn't do anything. Keyboard still couldn't recognize the enter key. It would just do nothing.

If I replace all `||` with `&&`, it will immediately exit the program.

Comment: Try changing `while((ch=mygetch()) != EOF || ch != 13 || z<sizeof(password)-1)` to `while((ch=mygetch()) != EOF && ch != 13 && z<sizeof(password)-1)`

Comment: @CoolGuy : Yes, I tried it but it didn't work as well. It couldn't recognise the `enter` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the newline is assumed CR (= 13). But it can be LF (= 10). Please try to add one more condition to the while loop:

```
while((ch=mygetch()) != EOF || ch != 10 || ch != 13 || z<sizeof(password)-1) {
```

Comment: Okaay, so it worked already. Enter really is `10`. However, what happens is that, in the program you see, I asked users to input their username first. When user hits `enter` after inputting their username, `mygetch` would immediately get that `enter` as first character for password and will not even enter the loop (thus explains why it will immediately exit the program if I use `&&`). Problem is not really with the ascii, but with `mygetch`. Just tweaked a few lines and it already works. Thank you very much for the guide.

Answer (score 0):

Use `&&`, and add LF condition

```
while((ch=mygetch()) != EOF && ch != 13 && ch != 10 && z<sizeof(password)-1){
```